How get #document not equal on src iframe?
I use playwright python, i need get a url in iframe, this url generate not understandable for me.
iframe src url1 != #document(url2)
i try all my knowledges about iframe:
get_src
go in iframe and get content, it return loading circle
i try get all html of site, there no this url
idk what do with this, chat gpt says it is because security risks? idk what illegal in this
there what i want to get #document
frame = self.browser.contexts[0].pages[0].frame_locator('iframe[class="cashbox"]')
in the site look like in simple, I don't know how to reproduce this for the test:
<iframe src="https://example1.com" class="cashbox">
 #document(https://example2.com)
   <body>
     <div id="requisite">+7-987-654-32-10</div>
   </body>
</iframe>
so next i dont understand to do, thanks for all, it will be enough to get the url2 link using playwright
